# 'Outdated HTTPS configuration detected on the site'

Tags: php, ssl, tls1.2

I'm getting the following error from google:

```
Google has detected that your site is using an obsolete version of TLS (TLSv1).
```

My hosting providers say that it's not possible to update the version of TLS on the server as the server is running PHP 5.2.17 (due to it currently running an antique application).

The Apache version is 2.2.34.

Is it possible to update TLS whilst keeping this version of PHP?

What are the consequences of running TLS v1?

Comment: Are we talking about inbound traffic (i.e., the app is being served over HTTPS) or outbound traffic (i.e., the app is calling out to an HTTPS site)?

Comment: TLS is configured in Apache and not PHP. But it is probably also running an antique version of Apache as well in order to run the antique version of PHP

Comment: if you google "tls 1.0 vulnerabilities" there are lots of discussions of the possible risks

Comment: If  you absolutely cannot upgrade, the only solution I see would be to add a proxy in front to offload the SSL.  Provider based would be best (load balancer for exemple) or you could do it in another Apache.  Then the apache where your application runs must block everyone BUT the proxy to connect to it.  This way the browser only knows of the new Apache proxy, which has a recent and strong SSL.

Comment: @Nic3500 probably worth adding that the onward connection from the proxy to the main webserver must be secure over the wire somehow as well and not vulnerable to interception - perhaps by making that physically a private connection (i.e. shut the main webserver off from the internet entirely and move it inside the network, if that's possible)

Comment: Hi @AlexHowansky the app is being served over HTTPS

Comment: Ok, then there is no reason why you can't run an up-to-date version of Apache (or nginx) with an up-to-date version of OpenSSL (or LibreSSL) and an old version of PHP. Your host simply wants to avoid compiling custom versions of things and keep their server limited to the existing binary packages for the aging platform. You can either move the site to a VPS where you have full control over things yourself, or (as others have mentioned) set up a reverse proxy.

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, I thought that they were independent, but I assume there may be a shared resource that's stopping the upgrade?

Comment: The only thing stopping the upgrade is your host's stance on what they're willing to support. When they say, "It's not possible," what they mean is, "It's possible but it's not trivial so we're not going to do it."

Comment: Just thought of another possibility -- you might be able to run your app in a Docker container. Then you can move it to a new(ish) server that has modern crypto and the proxying just becomes a local port forward.